React Native Android: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method removeLast()Ljava/lang/Object
I have an android application built on React Native. It has worked fine through multiple updates over the past few months, but out of nowhere I started getting this error when building it. The app will not start up at all.
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                   
Process: com.appname.appname, PID: 30423
                                                                                                    
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method removeLast()Ljava/lang/Object; in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
                                                                                                        
at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.obtainDrawingOp(ScreenStack.kt:319)
                                                                                                        
at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.drawChild(ScreenStack.kt:303)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4317)
                                                                                                        
at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStack.dispatchDraw(ScreenStack.kt:288)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22747)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)

                                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4540)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22712)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRender
er.java:694)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:700)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:798)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4939)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4643)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3822)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2465)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9305
)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1339)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1348)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:882)
                                                                                                        
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1322)
                                                                                                        
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
                                                                                                        
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeIni
t.java:552)
                                                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

In my build.gradle I have the below but this has been consistent and I did not upgrade anything. I also did not update any packages as far as I can remember, although I've read that maybe this is related to react-native-screens?
I'd love some help on this. My app won't even start up. It's supposed to open to the main screen, auto log the user in and transition to the home page but it crashes before you can even see anything. It just shows this error.
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 24
compileSdkVersion = 35
targetSdkVersion = 35
ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"

My package.json has the following:
"dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.6.0",
    "@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native": "^1.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.5.0",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^19.3.0",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.84",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@sharpsports/sharpsports-mobile": "2.5.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "core-js": "^3.36.1",
    "firebase": "^10.11.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.10",
    "react-native-iap": "^12.15.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.10.3",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },


There's an error int he kotlin of your library.  You'd need to post the code for us to tell what.  It's not finding a function, which may be that it was incorrectly pruned by R8 or something similar.

Actually there is no removeLast on List, so either they added it via kotlin extention functions and the function got stripped incorrectly, or it shouldn't have compiled in the first place.

I appreciate the responses. I actually figured this out. The issue was a problem with react-native-screens. It was outdated and using removeLast() under the hood and that was causing the problem. I'll post a formal answer.

I figured this out. The problem was that...
compileSdkVersion = 35
targetSdkVersion = 35

was not happy with my version of react-native-screens. That library was using removeLast() under the hood, and as a result was causing problems. I updated this to the latest version (3.35.0 at the time of writing this).
Initially this did not fix the problem but I also ran cd android && ./gradlew  clean and also went to Android studio and closed my emulator and ran another "clean project" from there. After all this, I rebooted and things worked. The reason upgrading react-native-screens didn't initially work was likely because I was running a cached version of my app.
